# How can I implement the search for a location?

Tags: android, rest

I am planning on making a widget for android.  It will basically show pollution data that is gotten from a government data rest endpoint.

My problem is that I want the user to search for and select the location they want data for, much like the weather widget.

I'm thinking that having a persistence database is overkill because the data probably won't ever change and I don't think the location list very big.

Should I put a textfile in the app that is being searched through or is there another more efficient way to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516791/how-to-implement-a-search-for-location-in-android

Comment: I'll look into the geocoder.  That might be helpful!!! @VenkiWAR